# cron job + understanding where the script is run from

Tags: linux, cron

My script is in this directory: `/home/sims/user1/live`

but in cron it runs the script `nelist_format.sh` from here:
`/home/sims` even tho the script is not located there

my cron job looks like this:

```
48 9 * * * /home/sims/user1/live/nelist_format.sh >> /home/sims/user1/live/logs/nelist_format`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1
```

my work around is to change directory in my script

```
echo "$(pwd)"
cd /home/sims/user1/live #I have to change directory here else cron will run the file from /home/sims directory when I want to run it from cd /home/sims/user1/live
echo "$(pwd)"
```

But I am just trying to understand this process better.

Why is cron running my script from `/home/sims` when I was thinking it would be run from `/home/sims/user1/live`

Answer (score 0):

Cron always runs jobs from the root of the user directory (`/home/sims/`). That becomes the current working directory.

You can, at the cron level, `cd` and then execute the command:

```
48 9 * * * cd /home/sims/user1/live && /home/sims/user1/live/nelist_format.sh >> /home/sims/user1/live/logs/nelist_format`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.log 2>&1
```